# Some user attributes not showing up in django admin

Tags: django, django-admin, django-authentication

In my custom authentication backend I extract the username, email, first and last name from an LDAP response and try to stick them into a newly generated User object if the user doesn't yet exist:

```
user = User(username=username, email=result[0][1].get('mail')[0], first_name=result[0][1].get('givenName')[0], last_name=result[0][1].get('sn')[0])
user.save()
```

And another variant I tried:

```
user = User.objects.create_user(username, result[0][1].get('mail')[0])
user.first_name = result[0][1].get('givenName')[0]
user.last_name = result[0][1].get('sn')[0]
user.save()
```

While the username and email show up in the admin after the user's initial successful authentication attempt I can't get the first and last name to display. Logging the values from the LDAP response shows that these exist.

Any idea what's going wrong here?

Comment: Are the values for `first_name` and `last_name` showing up properly in the database? In other words, are you asking how to get the admin interface to display them, or are you running into a situation where they're not even getting to the database?

Comment: Sorry for having been unclear about this. I just checked and they don't even show up in the database...

Comment: In that case, I'd suggest looking at what, exactly, `result[0][1].get('givenName')[0]` and `result[0][1].get('sn')[0]` are returning, either using print statements or dropping into a debugger.  I suspect you're not getting anything there, but without knowing more about your setup I couldn't say why.  (If you want to try a debugger, pdb is pretty good; somewhere near this code you can insert a line with `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` to drop into it; Google `pdb` for some basics of how to use it.)

Comment: As I said in my original message, the values from the LDAP response do come through. So I suspect some stupid mistake on my part (very likely) or a bug (pretty unlikely that nobody stumbled upon this before...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it was indeed my own stupidity: should not only have restarted the frontend webserver but also uWSGI! I could add to my defense that these are my baby steps with uWSGI...